# Is there a way to position elements in select > option?

Tags: html, css, html-select, positioning

I want to position 2 P elements so they would look like their parent (option) had justify-content:space-between.

```
<optgroup label="select">
     <option value="option"><p>p1</p><p>p2</p></option>
</optgroup>
```

Is there a way to do it in css? I would also like to remove / replace borders.

Comment: Invalid HTML markup. `<option>` is not allowed to have child tags within.

Comment: Is there any other way to have 2 spearated text elements in it?

Comment: only if you build a custom select box. Not with the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Option tags do not accept children tags, the DOM with treats whatever you put inside of the `<option>` as text.  See [MDN's Option documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) for more info.

What most people will do if they need to have custom-styled dropdowns/select groups, is to recreate the behavior in HTML & JS.  Here's a great article on the balance between custom elements, and user accessibility from CSS Tricks.

[Striking a Balance Between Native and Custom Select Elements](https://css-tricks.com/striking-a-balance-between-native-and-custom-select-elements/)

Comment: Please read [answer]. Your answer effectivly is 
a [link only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and as such does not meet the guidelines 
as an answer.

Comment: While I don't agree that this is a link-only answer, please add some more explanation to go with the linked article.